# Button changes location when returning to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a `view` that contains a `TableView` , `UIImage` and a `UIButton`. The `UIButton` is configured in the IB and located like this: `self.camButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410,127,49);` My problem is that the `UIButton` changes its location when I'm poping back to the first `ViewController`. On first load it's located fine but when I'm coming back to the `ViewController` the button is located about 20 pixels up in the view. I'm trying to log the location fo the button so I got inside `viewWillAppear`:
`NSLog(@"Bug Fixes: %f",self.camButton.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"Bug Fixes: %f",self.view.frame.origin.y);` But I'm always getting 410 and 0 on first load and when the button is misplaced. I'm playing around with the `View` location in other `ViewControllers` (while showing keyboard for example I push up the `view`) but I don't think that's what causing it because the view stays in the same location when I'm returning to the first `ViewController`

Comment: Are you using constraints on your IB layout?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can i check ?

Comment: I'm not using AutoLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

you Need to set `autoresizingMask`

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

For more Information check this [link](http://nachbaur.com/blog/basics-positioning-uiviews)

Answer (score 0):

If you have autoLayout enabled then look for the constraints.

Second way is to use initWithFrame: whenever you return back to that view.

Comment: I'm not using autoLayout. How do I use initWithFrame?

Comment: create a frame with NSRect giving x, y, height, width... and assign that one to the button in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code

```
self.camButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410,127,49);
```

in  `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. The Console already tells me that that's the button location when it's not.

Comment: are you doing some thing with the orientation change on the button ??? if yes check for it

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set the Frame of the Button (loadview, viewwillappear, etc...) and where do you allocate the Button?  Do you nil the button in dealloc? try to set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMaring | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin.

Comment: I don't allocate the button. I just placed it with the IB and configured it. Then changed in location with the code.

Comment: Ok, so probably the 2 Values from IB and your code differs by 20px. Where do you set the Frame?? If the view reloads after poping and your manual CGRectMake does not get called, we found it, because it loads the values from IB.

Comment: That's not it, the frame in the IB is set way up on the viewController to avoid cases like that. I only set the location of that button once and check it's location in `viewWillAppear'. I don't understand how the console tells me one thing and the view tells me another.

Comment: where do you log the frame? try it in viewDidAppear, because in viewWillAppear, the view still is not visible yet